# Crazy... button.setOnClickListener java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, button, nullpointerexception

Honestly...I'm getting crazy about this error.. =)) I would pay you a dinner for this one..

I'm having a **java.lang.NullPointerException** in a button. The error, is on the code (MainActivity, function doReport() ):

```
ReportDialog = new Dialog(this);        
ReportDialog.setCancelable(true);
ReportDialog.setContentView(R.layout.report);
ReportDialog.setTitle("GeoClient Report");

button_report = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_report);

button_report.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { // line 274 **ERROR** NullPointerException
@Override
public void onClick(android.view.View v) {}  });
```

The layout:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/button_report"
android:layout_width="500dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Report" />
```

More details:

1. I've togglebuttons exactly in the same situation, and they're working... (view is clickable, i guess)
2. If I leave uncommented the code button_report = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_report); and comment // button_report.setOnClickListener(... it works! (therefore, The button is found on the layout)
3. The layout is called as dialog, the code

   ReportDialog = new Dialog(this);
   ReportDialog.setCancelable(true);
   ReportDialog.setContentView(R.layout.report);
   ReportDialog.setTitle("GeoClient Report");

Finally the stack:

```
11-07 02:47:52.179: E/Teste(10730): TOAST: doLogin: A fazer Report!!!
11-07 02:47:52.519: D/AndroidRuntime(10730): Shutting down VM
11-07 02:47:52.519: W/dalvikvm(10730): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417aa930)
11-07 02:47:52.597: E/AndroidRuntime(10730): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-07 02:47:52.597: E/AndroidRuntime(10730): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-07 02:47:52.597: E/AndroidRuntime(10730):    at com.geoclient.MainActivity.doReport(MainActivity.java:274)
11-07 02:47:52.597: E/AndroidRuntime(10730):    at com.geoclient.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:503)
11-07 02:47:52.597: E/AndroidRuntime(10730):    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2597)
11-07 02:47:52.597: E/AndroidRuntime(10730):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1031)
11-07 02:47:52.597: E/AndroidRuntime(10730):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
11-07 02:47:52.597: E/AndroidRuntime(10730):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
11-07 02:47:52.597: E/AndroidRuntime(10730):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
11-07 02:47:52.597: E/AndroidRuntime(10730):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ListMenuPresenter.onItemClick(ListMenuPresenter.java:166)
11-07 02:47:52.597: E/AndroidRuntime(10730):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
11-07 02:47:52.597: E/AndroidRuntime(10730):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
11-07 02:47:52.597: E/AndroidRuntime(10730):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
11-07 02:47:52.597: E/AndroidRuntime(10730):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3424)
11-07 02:47:52.597: E/AndroidRuntime(10730):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
11-07 02:47:52.597: E/AndroidRuntime(10730):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-07 02:47:52.597: E/AndroidRuntime(10730):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-07 02:47:52.597: E/AndroidRuntime(10730):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
11-07 02:47:52.597: E/AndroidRuntime(10730):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-07 02:47:52.597: E/AndroidRuntime(10730):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-07 02:47:52.597: E/AndroidRuntime(10730):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
11-07 02:47:52.597: E/AndroidRuntime(10730):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
11-07 02:47:52.597: E/AndroidRuntime(10730):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-07 02:47:54.773: I/Process(10730): Sending signal. PID: 10730 SIG: 9
```

Comment: `button_report = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_report);` this code will find `R.id.button_report` from your activity, not your dialog, hence the `NullPointerException`. Consider to create a custom dialog by following [the official docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

Comment: button_report = (Button) ReportDialog .findViewById(R.id.button_report); if button is in report layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If** your button is in Dialog

then `button_report = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_report);`
change this line to

```
button_report = (Button)ReportDialog.findViewById(R.id.button_report);
```

As it will find your button in your main layout view nd it does not find this Dialog's component in your main view. so define its view while instantiating it.

**else**

Change your click event to:

```
button_report = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_report);

button_report.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {}  });
```

chnge `android.view.View` to Only  `View`

Comment: ohh man.. it was so easy!! thanks so much... I was looking, but not seeing.. I could passed all night looking to this, and not see it.. many thanks!!

Comment: Thanks additionally for the android.view.View tip! I originally had only 'View' but I got into 'desperate mode'.. and try everything =P